# In a set we have $a(b+c)=ab+c$. What is it?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

suppose $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and for any $a,b,c\in A$ with $a<b<c$ we have
$$a(b+c)=ab+c$$
what are all $A$ with this property?!

here $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,...\}$.

Comment: We have $ac = c$, so with $a < b < c$ this forces $A$ to have at most 3 elements and $1 \in A$ (or it can have less that three elements, and then the premise is false).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the distributive property, subtract the common term, and you get $ac=c$, so $a=1$.  Any three element subset that includes $1$ will force this.  Any set with less than three elements will also meet the requirement as there is no $a,b,c$.

Comment: What about $A = \varnothing$?